# Cannot pip install CUDA-enabled pytorch in nvidia/cuda docker container: not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, docker, pip, pytorch

I have an image (`./app/Dockerfile`) defined like this:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-base-ubuntu20.04
ENV TZ="Asia/Kuala_Lumpur"
################################################################################
#
#   Ubuntu 20.04, Cuda 11.3, python3.10
#
################################################################################

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# apt update
RUN apt update

# install python 3.10
RUN apt install -y software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt install -y python3.10 && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3-pip python3.10-dev python3.10-distutils python3.10-venv && \
    cd /usr/local/bin && \
    ln -s /usr/bin/python3.10 python
```

Then, in a docker compose file, I have a service defined like this:

```
services:
  app:
    runtime: nvidia
    build:
      context: ./app
    image: ubuntu-cuda
```

Then when I try to pip install this version of pytorch specifically (from inside the container):

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch-1.12.1%2Bcu113-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: torch-1.12.1+cu113-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I checked that python3.10 is successfully installed in the container:

`python --version`

```
Python 3.10.13
```

But I can't run nvidia-smi (from inside the container) to check for some reason ... But when I do:

```
docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all ubuntu-cuda  nvidia-smi
```

I have the output:

```
Tue Sep  5 12:03:02 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03   Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
```

Then, `uname -a` from inside the container:

```
Linux 0fe451225d84 5.4.0-135-generic #152-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 23 20:19:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So it's not the wrong python installation, it's not the wrong playform ... what could be the problem?

I can run install `pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch-1.12.1%2Bcu113-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl` fine on the host with similar system configuration.

On the host:

`uname -r`

```
Linux opus 5.4.0-135-generic #152-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 23 20:19:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`nvidia-smi`

```
Tue Sep  5 12:08:22 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03   Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
```

`python --version`

```
Python 3.10.9
```

Comment: It turns out `pip` was using the default `python3.8` installation (can check this with `pip install -v`) ...

Answer (score 2):

Try to add:

```
FROM python:3.10-bookworm
```

on the second line of `Dockerfile`, and remove the other installs of python.
You will get:

```
root@db6eeaa35c05:/# pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch-1.12.1%2Bcu113-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting torch==1.12.1+cu113
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch-1.12.1%2Bcu113-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl (1837.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.8/1.8 GB 734.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting typing-extensions (from torch==1.12.1+cu113)
  Obtaining dependency information for typing-extensions from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ec/6b/63cc3df74987c36fe26157ee12e09e8f9db4de771e0f3404263117e75b95/typing_extensions-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Downloading typing_extensions-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
Downloading typing_extensions-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions, torch
Successfully installed torch-1.12.1+cu113 typing-extensions-4.7.1
```